# 3-way mergesort

Tags: java, arrays, merge, mergesort

I have as an assignment to implement something like a 3-way mergeshort in java. I will have as an input an array of integers and I have to do the following:

Implement mergesort in arrays with a 3-way division and also print the 3 sorted partitions of the array. For example if I have as an input the following array `[9 23 10 90 70 10 3 23]` the output would be firstly the 3 partitions sorted: `[9 10 24]` `[70 90]` `[3 10 23]` and then the final array sorted `[3 9 10 10 23 24 70 90]`.

This is what I have implemented so far:

```
public static void mergesort(int[] data) {
    int elements = data.length - 1;
    int length1;
    int length2;
    int length3;

    if (elements % 3 == 0) {
        length1 = elements / 3;
        length2 = elements / 3;
        length3 = elements / 3;
    } else if (elements % 3 == 1) {
        length1 = (elements / 3) + 1;
        length2 = elements / 3;
        length3 = elements / 3;
    } else { //if (elements % 3 == 2)
        length1 = (elements / 3) + 1;
        length2 = elements / 3;
        length3 = (elements / 3) + 1;
    }

    Arrays.sort(data, 0, length1 - 1);
    Arrays.sort(data, length1, length1 + length2 - 1);
    Arrays.sort(data, length1 + length2, length1 + length2 + length3 - 1);

    merge(data, 0, length1, length1 + length2);
    merge(data, 0, length1 + length2, length1 + length2 + length3);
}

private static void merge(int[] data, int first, int n1, int n2) {
    int[] temp = new int[n1 + n2];
    int copied = 0;
    int copied1 = 0;
    int copied2 = 0;
    int i;

    while ((copied1 < n1) && (copied2 < n2)) {
        if (data[first + copied1] < data[first + n1 + copied2]) {
            temp[copied++] = data[first + (copied1++)];
        } else {
            temp[copied++] = data[first + n1 + (copied2++)];
        }
    }

    while (copied1 < n1) {
        temp[copied++] = data[first + (copied1++)];
    }
    while (copied2 < n2) {
        temp[copied++] = data[first + n1 + (copied2++)];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n1 + n2; i++) {
        data[first + i] = temp[i];
    }
}
```

What I've done is first of all split the array in 3 parts depending the circumstances, after that I sort the 3 parts of the array and later I try merging the first 2 parts and then the combined part with the last part.

I have implemented these 2 methods for starters but first of all I'm pretty confident that the merge method is awful and wrong and second of all I believe something is wrong with my approach in this problem I feel that even the mergesort method is wrong and awfully implemented.

What I want is advice as to what I should be doing in this problem and what is totally wrong with my implementation

Comment: How exactly are you supposed to divide the arrays by 3? Using the indices of the original unsorted array or something else?

Comment: No, that is fine. Can you post the output/error/exceptions of your code?

Comment: I actually have no errors in my code it's just that I'm pretty sure it doesn't work but even if it does work this doesn't seem the right way to solve this that's why I'm asking if I'm doing something really bad here because that is how it seems to me. By the way I haven't tested the numbers i just know that I have no errors in the code so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void merge(int arr1[], int arr2[])
{
  int p1 = 0;
  int p2 = 0;
  int arr3[] = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];

  while(p1 < arr1.length && p2 < arr2.length)
  {
    if(arr1[p1] > arr2[p2])
    {
      arr3[p2] = arr2[p2];
      p2++;
    }
    else
    {
      arr3[p1] = arr1[p1];
      p1++;
    }
  }

  //Now just add the code for just concatenating any remaining elements in 
  // either arr1 or arr2
  //This will happen if the lengths of arr1 and arr2 differ 


}
```

This is the basic code for merging two arrays (Not tested, might miss boundary conditions). Try to incorporate it to your code.